# Given a line number, how to read it from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Heres my code:

```
def option_a():
    fixchoice = int(input("Enter: "))

    file = open("firesideFixtures.txt", "r")
    print(file.readlines(fixchoice))

option_a()
```

Whenever I input any number, it always prints the same line.

Comment: can you show us Expected and Actual output of your code?

Comment: Specifically, what's in the file, what numbers are you inputting, and what do you expect the corresponding results to be?

Comment: Your argument to `readlines` [does not do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=readlines#codecs.StreamReader.readlines) what you seem to think.

Comment: What is the meaning of `fixchoice`? Is it the number of lines? Is it the line number?

Comment: fixchoice is the is the line number. expected is that the inputted number (fixchoice) is the line that should be printed.

Comment: You need to read up a bit on [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines): "no more lines will be read **if the total size (in bytes/characters)** of all lines so far exceeds hint."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a covenient [`linecache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html) library to deal with your situation:

```
import linecache

def option_a():
    line_number = int(input("Enter a line number: "))
    line = linecache.getline("firesideFixtures.txt", line_number)
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to readlines() doesn't specify which line to read from the file.  Try something like this instead:

```
def option_a():
    fixchoice = int(input("Enter: "))

    with open("firesideFixtures.txt", "r") as file:
        for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            if i == fixchoice:
                print(line)
                break # Or return if you don't want to do anything after the loop

option_a()
```

Comment: Each time that function is called, it leaves a file handle open. I suggest you use `file.close()` after the loop.

Comment: .. or use the more transparent `with` syntax.

Comment: `enumerate` by default will start with zero. Line numbers usually start with one. When the user types **1**, he or she wants line 1, not line 2. You can fix it with `enumerate(file, 1)` to start with one instead of zero.

Comment: Good inputs all of you, I've updated my example to include that.  I didn't intend to make an entire workable example, only fix the issue in the question itself, but it might be best I guess.